# Extracting metadata info of cardano tokens

Tags: cardano-db-sync, metadata, token

I am currently working with cardano-db-sync and I am doing research to extract the metadata of all the native tokens. I found out the policy id and asset name can be extracted from cardano-db-sync but the remaining metadata info should be queried from the metadata server. I am not able to find anything useful related to metadata server. I mean to say what metadata server should I use or setup?

Answer (score 1):

The current off-chain metadata registry is hosted by the Cardano Foundation.

Their endpoint is `https://tokens.cardano.org/metadata` and you can find the registry itself along with the documentation [hosted on github.com](https://github.com/cardano-foundation/cardano-token-registry).

Right now, the software does not support setting up a mirror of the current registry, which might be annoying as their rate-limiting is pretty strict. At [Blockforst](https://blockfrost.io/), we have developed a tool to convert the current registry files to the output you are expecting - it is called [`metadada`](https://github.com/blockfrost/metadada) and is open source.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but i was trying to get the onchain metadata and i don't seem to get it from cardano dbsync. I need to fetch every data and stored it in a table.

Comment: In that case, you might refer to the NFT metadata according to CIP-25? If that is the case, your question is misleading as it talks about the metadata server for native assets , which is what I described in my answer. You might want to submit another question if it is about an SQL query in cardano-db-sync.